# Matching regex for /Hello/World

Tags: regex, oracle

I need a regex to match **Hello** from /Hello/World.

```
I tried
\/\w+/

But this matches
/Hello/
```

Any ideas ?

I am using Oracle SQL.

Comment: What is the language you are using? And please add the corresponding tag.

Comment: @Jhon Please aAdd the proper tags while asking a question.

Comment: @Tim accepted answer suggest lookarounds. So I think oracle supports lookarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using Javascript you can use look behind like:

```
(?<=\/)\w+
```

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eY6zD8/1)**

If you are using Javascript then you could use lookahead like, although this will also work with other languages as well:

```
\w+(?=\/)
```

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yQ6zR0/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to capture the matched context that you want and refer back to the matched group to access your match result.

```
/(\w+)/
```

Depending on what verion of Oracle you are using, try the following:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('/Hello/World', '/(\w+)/', 1,1,NULL,1) from dual;
```

The last parameter indicates the number of the capture group you want returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression `\/(\w+)\/`. You can then retrieve this [*captured group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) from your regular expression matcher.

In Java, for example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\/(\w+)\\/");
Matcher m = p.matcher("/Hello/World");
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // Hello
```

Or Python:

```
In [5]: re.match(r'\/(\w+)\/', '/Hello/World').group(1)
Out[5]: 'Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intentions are to do this in Oracle SQL, perhaps the regexp_replace
function is what you need:

```
regexp_replace ('/Hello/World', '/(\w+)/\w+', '\1' )
```

**Explanation:**

The problem you identify appears to be well suited for the regexp_replace
function:

Search by string: `'/(\w+)/\w+'`

Replace by string: `'\1'`

Here, `'\1'`, is just a character group referencing, `'(\w+)'`, in the search by
string.

This is just a slight variation of hwnd's solution. Oracle SQL does not have the lookahead assertion functionality.